# Preventing hover on elements that cover a hovered element

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am working with SVG and Raphael JS. I have a situation where if you hover over an element a second element appears on top of the first element. When the second element appears the mouse is now over the second element and therefore the mouseout event fires on the first element and hides the second element. This continues in a loop. How can I prevent mouseout from occurring on the first element or prevent the hover on the second element?

In other examples I have tried I get a flickering effect. Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing in Raphael...

```
window.onload = function () {
  var paper = Raphael("container", 1000, 900);
  var rect_one = paper.rect(30, 30, 150, 150).attr({fill:"#fff"});
  var rect_two = paper.rect(50, 50, 60, 60).attr({fill:"#fff"});

  rect_two.hide();

  rect_one.mouseover(function () {
    rect_two.show();
  });

  rect_one.mouseout(function () {
    rect_two.hide();
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place your Raphael elements in a set then you can fix the problem:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var paper = Raphael("container", 1000, 900);
  var group = paper.set()
  var rect_one = paper.rect(30, 30, 150, 150).attr({fill:"#fff"});
  var rect_two = paper.rect(50, 50, 60, 60).attr({fill:"#fff"});
  group.push(rect_one);
  group.push(rect_two);
  rect_two.hide();

  group.mouseover(function () {
    rect_two.show();
  });

  group.mouseout(function () {
    rect_two.hide();
  });

};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agdMG/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The simple example above works. I can't seem to get the same result on the code I'm working on.

The problem I'm having is flickering when you hover over a path which is covered by another path.

See the example on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamoliver/YVHRY/

Comment: That's too much code for me to debug. If you want a quick fix you can add `pointer-events: none` though this won't work on older versions of IE http://jsfiddle.net/RHyAG/

Answer (score 0):

I rethought your solution, and came up with the following approach...

Rather than trying to trigger on a onmouseout event (which is triggered by the mouse going over the text box that contains the state name, thus the flickering that occurs as you move the mouse across the state/name area), I thought it might be more efficient to simply cache the currently-active state in a variable, and on mouse enter, test to see if the cached state matches the state that you're mousing over.

See the attached jsFiddle (a fork of your own), and the comments I've included in that script.

http://jsfiddle.net/XKt9U/8/

Comment: In a sense, what's happening in your original code is that the onmouseout event is being fired because your mouse is intersecting with another object (the state-name-box), which it counts as "out" of the state-object.